# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:at Datatypes.main(Datatypes.java:4)

Tags: java

```
package corejava;

public class Datatypes {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //byte
        byte num1 = 100;
        System.out.println(num1);
        
        //short
        short num2 = 100;
        System.out.println(num2);
        
        
        //int
        int num3 = 15000;
        System.out.println(num3);
        
        
        //long
        long num4 = 5555555555L;
        System.out.println(num4);
        
        
        //float
        float num5 = 15.254f;
        System.out.println(num5);
        
        
        //double
        double num6 = 15.28484;
        System.out.println(num6);
        
        
        //char
        char ch = 'A';
        System.out.println(ch);
        
        
        //String
        String str = "SG Testing Institute";
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

ERROR:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:

at Datatypes.main(Datatypes.java:4)

Comment: Please add more details to your problem

Comment: works fine on my computer. have you got JDK installed?

Comment: OK ... so it looks to me like you have not built the code correctly.  Specifically, it looks like you >had< a compilation error, you corrected it, but you didn't recompile the code.  And you are now running the ".class" file from >before< the compilation error was corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working perfectly fine in my pc ..giving below output

```
100 100 15000 5555555555 15.254 15.28484 A SG Testing Institute
```

Can you please check JDK settings

Comment: I did reinstall java and eclipse and then ran the code and it worked. Thanks a lot for all the answers